# Как двигать камеру с игроком на LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

Всем привет и у меня есть проблема по поводу отцентровки камеры на игроке. Я испробовал множество разных методов, но ни один не работает корректно.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    private Engine engine;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Stage stage;

    private float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    private float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    private PlayerButton playerButton = new PlayerButton();
    private FightButton fightButton = new FightButton();
    private SpeedUpButton speedUpButton = new SpeedUpButton();
    private Player player = new Player();
    private Controller controller = new Controller();
    private HealthBar healthBar = new HealthBar();
    private StrengthBar strengthBar = new StrengthBar();
    private Smartphone smartphone = new Smartphone();
    private SmartButton smartButton = new SmartButton();
    private BackgroundForGameScreen bg = new BackgroundForGameScreen();

    private Data data = new Data();

    public GameScreen(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(1000, 1000 * (h / w));
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2f, camera.viewportHeight / 2f, 0);
        camera.update();

        Preferences data = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Rainy East");
        boolean equp = data.getBoolean("DATA/isKatanaOn");

        if (equp) {
            player.setKatana(true);
            player.setMask(true);
        } else {
            player.setKatana(false);
            player.setMask(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
        multiplexer.addProcessor(playerButton.stage);
        multiplexer.addProcessor(smartButton.stage);
        multiplexer.addProcessor(fightButton.stage);
        multiplexer.addProcessor(speedUpButton.stage);
        multiplexer.addProcessor(smartphone.stage);

        stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(1000, 1000 * (h/w)));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);

        stage.addActor(bg);
        stage.addActor(player);
        stage.addActor(controller);
        stage.addActor(healthBar);
        stage.addActor(strengthBar);
        stage.addActor(playerButton);
        stage.addActor(smartButton);
        stage.addActor(fightButton);
        stage.addActor(speedUpButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (playerButton.isConfigBruh()) {
            engine.setScreen(new PlayerInventoryScreen(engine));
        }

        if (smartButton.isYouWannaThat()) {
            stage.addActor(smartphone);
        }

        SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();

        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        stage.getCamera().update();

        playerButton.act(delta);
        smartButton.act(delta);
        fightButton.act(delta);
        speedUpButton.act(delta);
        smartphone.act(delta);
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();

        float x = player.getX();
        float y = player.getY();

        boolean xf = controller.isXf();
        boolean xb = controller.isXb();
        boolean yf = controller.isYf();
        boolean yb = controller.isYb();

        if (xf) player.setX(x + 250*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        if (xb) player.setX(x - 250*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        if (yf) player.setY(y + 250*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        if (yb) player.setY(y - 250*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        if (camera.position.x < player.getX() && stage.getViewport().getCamera().position.x < player.getX()) {
            camera.position.x = player.getX();
            stage.getCamera().translate(player.getX(), player.getY(),0);
            stage.getCamera().update();
        }

        if (stage.getViewport().getCamera().position.x < player.getX()) {
            stage.getCamera().translate(50f, 0,0);
            stage.getCamera().update();
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
            camera.position.x -= 10;
            stage.getCamera().translate(1f, 0,0);
            stage.getCamera().update();
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
            camera.position.x += 10;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
            camera.position.y += 10;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) {
            camera.position.y -= 10;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
    }
```

Для понимания - игрок это прямоугольник с текстурой внутри.

Answer (score 1):

Так, посидел, подумал, и вот что получилось

```
if (camera.position.x < player.getX() + 75 * (h/w)) {
        camera.position.set(player.getX() + 75 * (h/w), camera.position.y,0);
        player.cam.position.set(player.getX() + 75 * (h/w), camera.position.y,0);
        stage.getCamera().update();
    }
    if (camera.position.x > (player.getX() + 75 * (h/w))) {
        camera.position.set(-(player.getX() + 75 * (h/w)), camera.position.y,0);
        player.cam.position.set(-(player.getX() + 75 * (h/w)), camera.position.y,0);
        stage.getCamera().update();
    }
    if (camera.position.y < (player.getY() + 150 * (h/w))) {
        camera.position.set(camera.position.x, player.getY() + 150 * (h/w),0);
        player.cam.position.set(camera.position.x, player.getY() + 150 * (h/w),0);
        stage.getCamera().update();
    }
    if (camera.position.y > (player.getY() + 150 * (h/w))) {
        camera.position.set(camera.position.x, -(player.getY() + 150 * (h/w)),0);
        player.cam.position.set(camera.position.x, -(player.getY() + 150 * (h/w)),0);
        stage.getCamera().update();
    }
```

Только при движении вниз и влево мерцает экран, но это уже думаю не трудно подправить. Ну и в метод Resize не забываем добавить строку:

```
stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
```